# Grunt and ECMA6Script

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, ecmascript-6

I have Grunt compiler for my project with jshint.

I use this syntax for multiline string:

```
string = '`
         Hello
`';
```

but I get this error when I compile it:

```
[L328:C33] W112: Unclosed string.
                    string = '`
```

Doesn't it support ECMA6 syntax?

Comment: I think you just have to write the backtick

let string = ` 
Hello

`

Answer (score 1):

Template strings (``) in ES6 are replacement for quotes ('').

You need to write it as:

```
let str = `
    Hello
`;
```

Comment: I think this project https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint doesn't support ECMA6

Comment: You need to first compile ES6 to ES5 using any compiler like babel, traceur. If any project doesn't perform this compilation then it won't support ES6 for now. Check https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ for native ES6 compatibility.

Comment: So i need to use another plugin for compile before with ecma6 and after with jshint?

Comment: @Davide Please accept the answer if it helped you in solving your problem.